# How do I populate current class with new class values?

Tags: c#, class-design

This one is a little difficult to explain so I'll show code first..

Note: Made example less confusing

```
public class Class1
{
     public string Title {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}


     public Class1(Class1 class1)
     {
         // ?? How do I populate current class with new class values?
         // ?? this = class1;  - Does not work
         // I want to avoid having to manually set each value
     }
}
```

Thanks for help.. here what I did.. Created this in my extension class.. so I can now do

```
Extensions.MapValues(class1, this);
```

```
    public static void MapValues(object from, object to)
    {
        var fromProperties = from.GetType().GetProperties();
        var toProperties = to.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (var property in toProperties) {
            var fromProp = fromProperties.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToLower() == property.Name.ToLower());

            if(fromProp == null) {
                continue;
            }

            var fromValue = fromProp.GetValue(from, null);
            if(fromValue == null) {
                continue;
            }

            property.SetValue(to, fromValue, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible without setting each value individually...

Comment: By new class values do you mean to initialize the values? Afraid you have to do that manually.

Comment: This is confusing. What does DataRow contain? What are you trying to do create an instance of Class1 from a DataRow?

Comment: what does `row.ToClass1()` actually do?

Comment: ToClass1 is just an extension that returns Class1 from a DataRow, so I can work with a complex type rather than a DataRow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll probably be *easier* to manually set each value.

That said, *if* the column name of the DataRow is the same for each property in your class, and *if* the types are equally the same, you could use Reflection to set the property name. You would do it somewhat like this:

```
public Class1(DataRow row)
{
    var type = typeof(Class1);
    foreach(var col in row.Table.Columns)
    {
        var property = type.GetProperty(col.ColumnName);
        property.SetValue(this, row.Item(col), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did something very similar to this.. posting what  I did..  Thanks!

Comment: @LeeHull: your edit has confused me. I must have misread your question; I thought you were trying to set values for Class1 from the DataRow

Comment: it was a little difficult to explain, probably should have shown Class1 passed in, instead of row, makes it confusing

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

You can either manually copy over the properties, or replace the constructor with a static factory method that returns `row.ToClass1()`.